# Ruby hash object sometimes unresponsive when running multiple threads (using parallels gem)

Tags: ruby, multithreading, hash

I'm not sure if this is specific to parallel or not but pretty much when there's a lot of stuff going on, say 100 threads, I will not be able lose access to a hash within the thread.

I have two hashes:

```
result = {"expires_on"=>"July 12, 2013", "registered_on"=>"July 12, 2012"}
domain_hash = {"id"=>"268083"}
```

When I try to merge them like this:

```
result_hash = domain_hash.merge(result)
```

I get an error, but only when there are lots of thread running, with one thread there's no problem. Here's the error:

```
#e.message
"no implicit conversion of nil into Hash"

#e.backtrace
["script.rb:438:in `merge'",
 "script.rb:438:in `block in check_all_in_parallel'",
 "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/parallel-1.2.0/lib/parallel.rb:419:in `call'",
 "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/parallel-1.2.0/lib/parallel.rb:419:in `call_with_index'",
 "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/parallel-1.2.0/lib/parallel.rb:235:in `block (3 levels) in work_in_threads'",
 "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/parallel-1.2.0/lib/parallel.rb:430:in `with_instrumentation'",
 "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/parallel-1.2.0/lib/parallel.rb:233:in `block (2 levels) in work_in_threads'",
 "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/parallel-1.2.0/lib/parallel.rb:227:in `loop'",
 "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/parallel-1.2.0/lib/parallel.rb:227:in `block in work_in_threads'",
 "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/parallel-1.2.0/lib/parallel.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in in_threads'"]
```

If I open up binding.pry in my rescue statement and try the same command it works without any problems (by the time I can use the pry console though most of the other threads have died off, at which point it works fine).

**Current Solution:**

```
#this fixes the problem by brute force, is not very elegant
merge_attempt = 0
while result_hash.nil?
  begin
    result_hash = domain_hash.merge(result)

  rescue => e
    puts "UNABLE TO MERGE #{domain} -- TRYING AGAIN #{merge_attempt}"
    merge_attempt += 1
  end
end
```

This can take up to 70,000 tries to work, but it is getting the job done.

I've also tried just ditching the merge command and doing my own merge like this:

```
result.each_pair do |x,y|
  domain_hash[x] = y
end
result_hash = domain_hash
```

But this gives me similar problems, variable result becomes unresponsive and I get an error that says something like `no method "each_pair" for variable result` -- or something like that.

I thought it might be memory or CPU getting too taxed. Memory usage is 2gb out of 16, and CPU load average is less than 0.5, so I don't think that's it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your `result` object is nil, so you can't merge it into a hash. Could you update your question with a code when this object is being created/populated?

Comment: @BroiSatse I edited the question and included the hash values. Both result and domain_hash are hashes and are set correctly, I just can't access them *sometimes*. In fact, the merge command works unless there are lots of threads running at once, at which point I get the error outlined in the question. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: What would be a result of wrapping call to merge with `Mutex.new.synchronize{ result_hash = domain_hash.merge(result) }`?

Comment: @newUserNameHere - THis error can only show up when `result` is nil. IT might be not nil in most of the case, however in this one failing case I can bet my head it is nil. Could you update the question with a code creating this object, not its content?

Comment: @mudasobwa I gave that a shot but saw no difference :(

Comment: @BroiSatse Unfortunately it's just too much code to post. I understand that in this one case it is nil, my question is why would that happen, and how to fix it? It is set to a hash comprised of strings, and if you look under the heading "Current Solution" in my question, you will see how I am working around this issue. Essentially I force the software to keep pulling the variable until it is not nil, which works (but shouldn't I don't think).